# How to determine the runtime dependencies of gcc-arm-none-eabi?

Tags: gcc, dependencies

## Background

There is [a GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88167) that affects Cortex M0 architecture which [seems to be introduced in v5.4.1](http://www.chibios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=5030&sid=68e7fb39c8c43df543c7dfa99c0d526d&start=10#p35130) (...and seems to be fixed in the trunk, however, we aren't interested in this option ATM).

In order to workaround the problem, I used a virtual machine with Debian 8.4 image and installed `gcc-arm-none-eabi` package:

```bsh
$ gcc-arm-none-eabi -dumpversion
4.8
```

When I compiled my code in the VM and load to the target device, the problem is vanished and everything went fine.

## Problem

In order to disintermediate the virtual machine,

- I downloaded `gcc-arm-none-eabi v5.3` from [developer.arm.com/...](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/5_3-2016q1/gccarmnoneeabi532016q120160330linuxtar.bz2?revision=417e2623-c259-4a12-aacc-c87200b569c7?product=GNU%20Arm%20Embedded%20Toolchain,32-bit,,Linux,5-2016-q1-update)
- Prepend the download path to the `$PATH` variable accordingly
- Run `make`

However, the generated code doesn't work as expected on the microcontroller. This means that I can't compile my code using gcc-arm-none-eabi-5.3 on my host machine.

## Further Experiments

In order to narrow down the problem,

- I compiled the application code (app) with same [gcc 5.3](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/5_3-2016q1/gccarmnoneeabi532016q120160330linuxtar.bz2?revision=417e2623-c259-4a12-aacc-c87200b569c7?product=GNU%20Arm%20Embedded%20Toolchain,32-bit,,Linux,5-2016-q1-update) on virtual machine (after installing [32bit support](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)). The generated binary run on target (microcontroller) **as expected.**
- I compiled the app with [gcc 7.3.1](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) while **expecting not to work**. However, the generated binary is able to run on microcontroller correctly. This was **not expected.**
- I removed `gcc-arm-none-eabi` with `apt-get remove` and retried previous attempt. The app binary still worked on the microcontroller, **which is not expected**.
- I restored the VM before I've installed `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4.8` via `apt`. I used `gcc-arm-none-eabi-7.3` directly from download path and *it didn't worked **as expected***
- I compiled the app with `gcc-arm-none-eabi-5.3`, expecting it to work correctly. However, it didn't work on the microcontroller. This was **not expected.**
- If I install the toolchain (v4.8) at this point with `apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi`, generated binary doesn't work on the microcontroller, which is **not expected** and *surprising*.
- If I revert the VM to fresh install again and install v4.8 with `apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi gdb-arm-none-eabi`, stock compiler **doesn't work** (this is also *surprising*)

## Question

According to the "further experiments", there should be some other dependencies used in the runtime. How can we determine those dependencies?